# How to validate the string with only specific letter and number?

Tags: php, regex

I want to validate the string containing characters `A`, `B`. `X` & `Y`. The character A & B must follow by the number but X, Y should not be.

```
// correct 
"A11X",
"A45YA1X",
"A1XXA999YYA1",

// Not correct
"A1A1AAX12",
"1A1Y32A1",
"CA1A1",
"A1C1",
```

I am using following regex command.

```
$flags = PREG_SET_ORDER;
        preg_match_all('/A|B(\d+)|.+/i', trim($command), $operations, $flags);
```

If the string is correct, it must return true otherwise it should return error message.

Comment: Is `A1B2A1` valid?

Comment: yes that is valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
^(?:[AB]\d+|[XY])+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/evF8Ul/2)

- This regex uses a non-capturing group that matches letter `A` or `B` followed by 1+ digits or using alternation matches letter `X` or `Y`.
- This group is repeated 1 or more times to allow repetitions of this sub-pattern in entire string.

Comment: my requirement slightly changed.A & B should be followed by number but X & Y only should not follow by any number. Only A, B, X, Y are valid char